# Issue with dropdown list in action bar

Tags: android

im having a problem with the dropdown list in the action bar in android, which is that the list doesnt show up. Im already read the other questions in stackoverflow and the guide in android.developers, but im still gettin the same result.
**In onCreate i have declared the ActionBar and give it the navigation mode type (which is deprecated but i cant find nothing similiar cause the guide isnt to helpfull in this aspect):**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);



}
```

**Im declared my objects to show up in the action bar:**

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflatebar = getMenuInflater();
    inflatebar.inflate(R.menu.inflate_activity, menu);

    MenuInflater bar = getMenuInflater();
   bar.inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);



    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**This is the menu item:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
 android:id="@+id/settings1"
 android:icon="@drawable/abc_btn_radio_material"
 android:showAsAction="always"

/>

</menu>
```

**And finally im declared the actions that the item will do:**

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_cart:
            Intent intentcam = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivity(intentcam);
            break;
        case R.id.settings1:
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.days, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            break;



    }


    return true;
}


}
```

**Heres the array:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="days">
    <item>Item 1</item>
    <item>Item 2</item>
    <item>Item 3</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

The camera action works perfect, but not the dropdown view.